# Error when building iConf.NET Demos. Namespace name 'iConfServer' cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, referenceerror, iconfsdk

I am trying to build iConf.NET demo for video conferencing SDK.

The projects have references to assemblies named:

- iConfClient.NET.dll
- iConfServer.NET.dll

The references are ok.

In code there are following lines:

```
using iConfServer.NET.HelperClasses;
```

..etc, which are causing the errors of type

> The type or namespace name 'iConfServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\iConfNetSDKDemos\PictureInPictureVideoPhone\MainForm.cs

Any help will be appreciated